# Django auto update the column to inactive when current datetime greater than stored column datetime

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-views

I have stored expired datetime of an account in during insert, I should update the account as "Inactive" when the current time is greater than stored expired datetime automatically.

I have table like below and it have a data stored in below format.

```
---|------------|-------------------|---------------------|----------    
id | account_id | created_date      |  expired_date       |status   |
---|------------|-------------------|---------------------|----------
1  |     1      |18-12-2018 12:30:16| 01-05-2019 00:00:00 | Active  |
---|------------|-------------------|---------------------|----------
```

On current date time is greater than expired date (01-05-2019 00:00:00)  I have to update the table status by Inacive.

```
timediff = datetime.datetime.now() > self.expired_date
if (timediff):
  TableClass.objects.filter(id=id).update(status='Inactive')
```

This function need to run when ever the account crossing the expired date.

Comment: Hi ! Could you please add few piece of code you've written ? So the community will help you to understand where you are stuck.

Comment: I have added some more details now plz check it

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this : https://github.com/tivix/django-cron

In any case there would be some polling happening. put up a cron job for the same.